# Autohotekey: How to extract text between two words with multiple occurrences in a large text document

Tags: regex, autohotkey, texttrimming

Using Autohotkey, I would like to copy a large text file to the clipboard, extract text between two repeated words, delete everything else, and paste the parsed text.  I am trying to do this to a large text file with 80,000+ lines of text where the start and stop words repeat 100s of times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Input Text Example

> Delete this   text
> De l e te this text
>
> **StartWord**
>
> Apples Oranges
> Pears Grapes
>
> **StopWord**
>
> Delete this   text
> Delete this text
>
> **StartWord**
>
> Peas Carrots
> Peas Carrots
>
> **StopWord**
>
> Delete this   text
> Delete this text

Desired Output Text

> Apples Oranges
> Pears Grapes
>
> Peas Carrots
> Peas Carrots

I think I found a regex statement to extract text between two words, but don't know how to make it work for multiple instances of the start and stop words. Honestly, I can't even get this to work.

```
!c::
Send, ^c
Fullstring = %clipboard%
RegExMatch(Fullstring, "StartWord *\K.*?(?= *StopWord)", TrimmedResult)
Clipboard := %TrimmedResult%
Send, ^v
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the match at StartWord, and then match all lines that do not start with either StartWord or StopWord

```
^StartWord\s*\K(?:\R(?!StartWord|StopWord).*)+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `StartWord\s*\K` Match StartWord, optional whitespace chars and then clear forget what is matched so far using `\K`
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\R` Match a newline
  - `(?!StartWord|StopWord).*` Negative lookahead, assert that the line does not start with Start or Stopword
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times to match at least a single line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vtK0vN/1).

Comment: After making sure StartWord and StopWord were alone on their own line, this totally worked.  I used notepad++ You are a wizard. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is only slightly different than @Thefourthbird's solution.

You can match the following regular expression with general, multiline and dot-all flags set<sup>1</sup>:

```
^StartWord\R+\K.*?\R(?=\R*^StopWord\R)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C7tT3o/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows:

```
^StartWord     # match 'StartWord' at the beginning of a line
\R+            # match >= 1 line terminators to avoid matching empty lines
               # below
\K             # reset start of match to current location and discard
               # all previously-matched characters
.*?            # match >= 0 characters lazily
\R             # match a line terminator
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  \R*          # match >= 0 line terminators to avoid matching empty lines
               # above
  ^StopWord\R  # Match 'StopWord' at the beginning of a line followed
               # by a line terminator
)              # end positive lookahead
```

<sup>1. Click on `/gms` at the link to obtain explanations of the effects of each of the three flags.</sup>

Comment: I will check this out later today, and mark one of these as best. Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with Autohotkey, but was pleasantly-surprised that it [supports `\K`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#anchor).